# Assistance with my Code - Automating Warehousing Inventory Control

Tags: python, helper, software-design

The code below is a personal project of mine. I am a BEGINNER, still learning everyday, so, it is not perfect. So, for the experienced individual some things may be redundant.

Problem Statement: Automate Warehousing Inventory Control

Issue: Once the amount of items on a pallet reaches a certain amount, if you request a higher amount than what is available it will not hit you with an error message. It will continue instead of stopping and giving you a message letting you know that you cannot do that or there is not enough product available.

"""
This is he file that has to be adjusted. From an inventory standpoint.
"""

```
class Product: #Parent of the class Product
    def __init__(self, name, width, length, height, weight_of_case, UPC, quantity):   #the __init__() is a method. Initializer, constructor.
        self.name = name  #parameters are the variables attached to the method.
        self.width = width
        self.length = length
        self.height = height
        self.weight_of_case = weight_of_case
        self.UPC = UPC
        self.quantity = quantity
        print("Product Created.")

"""
class Toilet_Paper(Product): #This is just to test the inheritance of the value
    pass #This would be considered the sibling of the Product class

class Snacks(Product): #This is just to test the inheritance of the value
    pass #This would be considered the sibling of the Product class
"""
class New_Product: #Parent of the class New_Product
    def __init__(self, new_name, new_width, new_length, new_height, new_weight_of_case, new_UPC, new_quantity):
        self.new_name = new_name  # parameters are the variables attached to the method.
        self.new_width = new_width
        self.new_length = new_length
        self.new_height = new_height
        self.new_weight_of_case = new_weight_of_case
        self.new_UPC = new_UPC
        self.new_quantity = new_quantity
        print("New Product Created.")
"""
class Drinks(New_Product): #This is just to test the inheritance of the value
    pass #This would be considered the sibling of the Product class
"""
p = Product(input("Name of Product: "), float(input("Width of case: ")), float(input("Length of case: ")), float(input("Height of case: ")),
            float(input("Weight of case: ")), input("Enter UPC: "), input("Enter amount of pieces: "))  #This is how you create a new product.

weight_of_case = p.weight_of_case #This gets the attribute within p.

def casesremaining(total_cases, cases_selected):
    return total_cases - cases_selected #if user enters more cases than are available to select, user should get a message saying "you canot select more cases than you have

def totalweight(weight_of_case, total_cases):
    return weight_of_case * total_cases

def weight_of_cases_selected(cases_selected, weight_of_case):
    return cases_selected * weight_of_case

total_cases = int(input("Enter amount of total cases on pallet: "))
total_weight = totalweight(float(weight_of_case), float(total_cases))
application = 1
yes = "yes"
no = "no"

print("Product added to pallet.")
print("Total weight of pallet is: {:.2f}.".format(total_weight))
print("Total amount of cases on a pallet is: ", total_cases)

while application == 1: #Could use "for cases in pallet():"
    case_selection = (input("Do you want to select a case? yes/no: "))
    if case_selection == yes:
        select = int(input("How many cases would you like to select? "))
        cases_selected = select
        total_weight_of_cases_selected = weight_of_cases_selected(float(cases_selected), float(weight_of_case))

        def remainingweight(total_weight, total_weight_of_cases_selected):
            return total_weight - total_weight_of_cases_selected

        remaining_weight = remainingweight(float(total_weight), float(total_weight_of_cases_selected))
        if cases_selected == select:
            total_cases_remaining = casesremaining(int(total_cases), int(cases_selected))
            total_cases = total_cases_remaining #Forgot to update the original variable from input.
            total_weight = remaining_weight #Same here. Remember to update variables as the program goes.
            print("Total weight now is: {:.2f}".format(remaining_weight))
            print("You know have ", total_cases_remaining, " cases remaining.")
        #work on this
            if cases_selected > total_cases:  # new 10/25/2020 #Continue to check this. Not working
                print("You cannot select more than what is available on the pallet.")
                print("You need to order more.") #make a def or modify the actual def already in place.
                yes = "yes" or "y" or "Yes"
                no = "no" or "n" or "No"
                order_more = input("Would you like to order more? yes/no")
                continue
        if total_cases == 0: #new part 10/1/2020
            print("Your total amount of cases on the pallet is ", total_cases_remaining, ".")
            print("You have no more cases on the pallet.")
            no = "no"
            add = "add"
            change = "change"
            add_cases = input("Would you like to add more cases on the pallet, or change product? (add/change/no) ")
            if add_cases == add:
                cases_to_add = int(input("How many cases would you like to add? "))
                total_cases = cases_to_add+total_cases_remaining
                total_weight = weight_of_case * cases_to_add
                print("You have added to your pallet, ", cases_to_add, " more cases.")
                print("Your total cases on pallet now is: ", total_cases, ".")
                print("Your total weight of pallet now is: {:.2f}.".format(total_weight))
            elif add_cases == change: #added on 10/12/2020 - May not work.
                new_p = New_Product(input("Name of Product: "), float(input("Width of case: ")), float(input("Length of case: ")), float(input("Height of case: ")),
                                    float(input("Weight of case: ")), input("Enter UPC: "), input("Enter amount of pieces: "))
                weight_of_case = new_p.new_weight_of_case  # This gets the attribute within p.
                total_cases = int(input("Enter amount of total cases on pallet: "))  # problem is not changing the value after input.
                total_weight = totalweight(float(weight_of_case), float(total_cases))
                print("New Product added to pallet.")
                print("Total weight of pallet is: {:.2f}.".format(total_weight))
                print("Total amount of cases on a pallet is: ", total_cases)
                continue
            else:
                if add_cases == no:
                    print("Thank you for using our application.")
                    break
    else:
        if case_selection == no or application == 0:
            print("Thank you for using our application.")
            break
```

#add option to add more products.
#Add the ability to pull the last 4 of the UPC via str (string) range 4:.
#That is to identify case easier and quicker by matching the last 4 of the UPC.

"""
"Also add the time each change has happened with date."
"The app calculates total amount of cases by the weight of each individual case.
"App recognizes different amount of cases per pallet, due to the weight.
"**Maybe you can add dimensions to specify the different types of products???**
"You are able to input the product ID.
"You are able to add UPC.
"Where or what can you use in order to keep multiple values(multiple locations holding cases) so that the app can continue to keep track of inventory? \n",
"""

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How can I have the code give out an error message, or try again message when you try to select a higher quantity than it is available on the pallet?